# link requires id but is nil when signed out and created error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have a nav bar that appears on every page of my website.  There is a link in the navbar like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Publish' , new_user_comic_title_path(user_id: current_user.id) %>
```

I am using the DEVISE gem.  Each user has many `Comic_titles`, which is why I have the `new_user_comic_title_path`.  The problem is, when the user is signed out, `current_user.id` = nil.  The error is below:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

I would like (1) the page to render without it throwing this error and (2) if the link is clicked and the user is not signed it, it redirects to the sign in page.

Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'Publish' , new_user_comic_title_path(user_id: current_user.id) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Publish' , sign_in_path %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Publish' , signed_in? ? new_user_comic_title_path(user_id: current_user.id) : sign_in_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise gem then

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'Publish' , new_user_comic_title_path(user_id: current_user.id) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Publish' , new_session_path(:user) %>
<% end %>
```